# i have import a project in android studio but all tags giving error message

Tags: android

I download this project [GitHub]https://github.com/mitchtabian/Google-Maps-2018 and when i imported this project in android studio all tags are showing error.and there is no option showing to run project.
as showing in figure all tags are red

[image]

**File not found: git.exe**
this message "File not found: git.exe" also showing in 'Event log'

**this is my .xml file code**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".simple">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/relLayout1"
                android:padding="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Enter you email"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textEmailReg"/>


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:hint="emter email"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textEmailReg"/>


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:hint="password"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/input_email"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_confirm_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:hint="password"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/input_password"/>


                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_register"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/input_confirm_password"
                    android:text="@string/register"
                    android:background="@drawable/theme_button"/>

            </RelativeLayout>



        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**My build.gradle code is following**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Share full code for xml file

Comment: i sure that there is no problem in code it all about import problem

Comment: You'll have to share code to see what's the problem

Comment: yes bro. i have updated my Question with code please check it now

Comment: That's  not the actual problem because even without git you can run project, so upload full error log of this

Comment: There's a problem with the project itself, I tried checking out from version control and downloading the project didn't help either.

Comment: Also, there's nothing wrong with the code files. it has something to do with version control